# Block the term "<ah ref" and similar html tags from form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

How to block the term "<ah ref" and similar html tags from form submission?  Block html tags from textarea.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Blocking submissions with HTML is often done by a WAF. Do a web search for "sanitize inputs" with your server-side stack technology to start with. Also, it may be better to just use proper encoding when outputting values rather than relying on sanitizing inputs, unless you want to permit certain HTML tags but not others.

Comment: Any HTML tag without a name attribute should not submit.  If it is in a form, of course.

Comment: Ok.pls help me.. cf7  form wordpress